# Symbian like internet connectivity in android?

Tags: connection-issues, internet

In Symbian, i can connect and disconnect internet connection directly from my PC. i.e. when i use a dial-up connection on PC the mobile works as a modem. The internet connection is established just for the PC (connection is **not shared** between mobile and PC) and mobile can not use the internet.

In android however the connection is first established on mobile and then **shared** with PC and i can not disconnect directly from my PC.

I want the Symbian like connectivity where i can connect/disconnect the internet connection from the PC and use it only on my PC(no sharing).

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) to achieve this (wow, Llama can do what [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can't? Or does *Tasker* just not mention it in [its manual](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/)?). Basically, it should work like this (taking from one of it's screenshots on the playstore app page):

When "charging at home" => Enable Wifi Hotspot

I know, that's not *exactly* what you described. But it should give you a raw idea. Get yourself the free *Llama* app from the Playstore, and take a closer look at its possibilities. You might find a "rule" closer to your requirements there.

Alternatively, there are other automation apps available (like e.g. the mentioned *Tasker*). One of them might do the job better for you (e.g. offering "USB connected" as condition, and "enable USB tethering" as action -- I would wonder if *Llama* could not do that as well). At least, this example should have got you started.